# select specific element from List by using protractor

Tags: protractor

can any one suggest me how to select specific element from list by using below code

Select City   Customer Support  Feature Request    Sales Enquiry   Bug Report   Payment Issue

Comment: Please post some code.  Cannot answer the question in its current state.

Comment: Please clarify your question and also add some stuff

Answer (score 0):

Please find a huge range of locator-possibilities on the [official Protractortest API Page](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder)

Every element on a page needs to be uniquely identifiable... else the page wouldn't work, no matter which technology. Therefore with the help of any of the above provided locator-possibilities you'll always find the element you're looking for.

And there is never a need for XPath.